# qemu_thread_create: Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: android-studio, emulation, qemu

I am trying to run a very simple app on the emulator, but every time it shows me the same error. The emulator loads and suddenly crashes but works fine on a real device.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.payal.happybirthday.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Happy Birthday! ;)"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/desert"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Error on run:

> C:\Users\Payal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_4_API_24 
>   Warning: requested ram_size 1536M too big, reduced to 1024M
>   Hax is enabled
>   Hax ram_size 0x40000000
>   HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
>   emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
>   emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
>   qemu: qemu_thread_create: Not enough storage is available to process this command.

Comment: Does your emulator works normally (like, without your app) ? Did you also tried to reinstall it ?

Comment: No. Even if i just run the emulator without actually launching it for my app. It crash closes within sometime.